# How to apply Pattern Decorator on subclass

Tags: java, subclass, decorator, instanceof

I want to apply Pattern Decorator to my Android Project, but in the decorators i loose the membership of an object to his class. For example, if I want to add a **Ball** in my **Level**, treatments in my decorator **ColRebondBord** are applied on **AbstractGameObject** not a Ball. So I can't know if my object is a Ball or a Wall. (one is a Circle, one is a Rectangle)

[image]

In Level.java:

```
AbstractGameObject ball = new Ball (sizeball, posX, posY);
ball = new ColRebondBord(ball);//ball will rebond on the border level(screen)
lvl.add(ball);//add the ball in the Level
```

In ColRebondBord.java:

```
public void collisionBorder(double xLeftTopCorner, double yLeftTopCorner, double width, double height)
{

    if(_GameObjectDecorated instanceof Ball) {
        //treatments for Ball Object but never comes here
    }
    if(_GameObjectDecorated instanceof Wall) {
        //treatments for Wall Object but never comes here
}
```

This is a capture of a breakpoint in collisionBorder, I thought it will come in the first IF, but no :

[image]

Does anybody know if I have to use polymorphism (so in that case, I have to do decorator for each object Ball and Wall) or other idea ?

---EDIT--- Reading the comments, there is 2 Solutions : (thanks to @GuillaumeS and @amdev)

- Do 2 subclass of ColRebondBord: ColRebondBordBall and ColRebondBordWall
- Do 2 decorators, one to decorate Ball and the other Wall

And maybe other propositions could be proposed

Comment: What is the declared type of GameObjectDecorated ? Have you tried to place a breakpoint to check the type of your object ?

Comment: @GuillaumeS I added for you a breakpoint capture. Thanks for you help

Comment: It seems that the type of GameObjectDecorated is MvtSensor.

Comment: You don't have to check subclass type when using decorator. Collision border for class "Ball" have to call super.collisionBorder(). And you have to implements two differents collisionsBorder() functions in two differents subclass, so instead of ColRebondBord, create subclass ColRebondBordBall and ColRevondBordWall.

Comment: @GuillaumeS Because in my real project I do :
`AbstractGameObject ball = new Ball(holeSize, 0, 0);ball = new MvtSensor(ball);ball = new ColRebondBord(ball);lvl.add(ball);`

Comment: @amdev OK. That's what I thought when I was saying "use polymorphism (so in that case, I have to do decorator for each object Ball and Wall)"

Comment: Also, wall and ball are concept really different, maybe you should use two differents decorator.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check subclass type when using decorator.Collision border for class "Ball" have to call super.collisionBorder().And you have to implements two differents collisionsBorder() function in two differents classe, so instead of ColRebondBord, create subclass ColRebondBordBall and ColRevondBordWall.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think carefully what you want to achieve. And then decide if the decorator is a good way to achieve this goal.

A decorator is usefull to apply some common "decoration" to  different but similar objects. For example a "BackgroundDecorator" might apply a background color to different shapes (a cricle, a rectangle ...). The base class have then to support a method "setBackground" the decorator can call.

The importand point here: the base class have to support the methods the decorator uses, such that you do not need some instanceof checks. It should be applyable to all the different sub classes (e.g. a "BorderDecorator" might require a "getBoundingBox" method in the baseclass. Then he can be applied to all kind of elements given they support the "getBoundingBox" method).

A decorator **could** be used for colision as well. Just define the methods needed for colision detection inside the base class (maybe abstract). A bounding box might be helpfull, or an polyline if you need more accurate detection.

Other ways then using a decorator come to mind when thinking about colision detection. Some kind of strategy maybe ... "GameObject.getColisionStrategy" ...

Comment: Your vision is interested, thanks. But I think to keep the amdev's proposition : to do 2 subclasses of ColRebondBord